# Write struct to binary file, then read file and print data.

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, mingw, fread

I'm self-studying C and trying to understand memory allocation and basic I/O. My code creates a "database" object which contains a pointer to an "address" struct. This last pointer I use as an array, and allocate for it the required space. I write the data to a file, and the I open the file to read back the data. Valgrind shows no memory issues.

However, when built and ran on Windows 7 (built with MingW gcc 4.8.1), it dies when it tries to read the file. Furthermore, under win 7, If I give a MAX_ROWS value of 26, the program enters an infinite loop.

Furthermore, I'm not sure about the efficiency/correctness of this piece of code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ROWS 1000 * 1000
#define MAX_DATA 512

typedef struct Address {
    int id;
    int set;
    char *name;
    char *email;
} Address;

typedef struct Database {
    int max_rows;
    int max_data;
    Address *rows;
} Database;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{       
    Database *db = malloc(sizeof(Database));
    if(db == NULL)  { 
        printf("Could not allocate mem for db");
        free(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    db->max_data = MAX_DATA;
    db->max_rows = MAX_ROWS;

    db->rows = malloc(sizeof(Address) * db->max_rows);
    if(db->rows == NULL) printf("Could not allocate mem for db->rows");

    // Create static data 
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {                
        Address addr = { .id = i, .name = "Jack Sparrow", .email = "jacksp@example.com"};
        // Assign it
        *(db->rows + i) = addr;
    }

    // Open a file to write the data
    FILE *f = fopen("temp.dat", "w+");
    if(!f) printf("Could not open file");

    // The reason I cannot write the struct in one move
    // is because it has been dynamically sized
    int rc = fwrite(&db->max_rows, sizeof(int), 1, f); 
    rc = fwrite(&db->max_data, sizeof(int), 1, f); 
    rc = fwrite(db->rows, sizeof(Address) * db->max_rows, 1, f);     
    if(!rc) printf("could not write db");

    fclose(f);
    free(db->rows);
    free(db);

    // Now let's read the file
    f = fopen("temp.dat", "r");
    if(!f) printf("Could not open file\n");

    // Create a new Database pointer to store file data
    Database *tmpdb = malloc(sizeof(Database));
    if(!tmpdb) printf("could not allocate memory to tmpdb\n");
    rc = fread(&tmpdb->max_rows, sizeof(int) , 1, f); 

    if(!rc) printf("could not read max_rows\n");
    rc = fread(&tmpdb->max_data, sizeof(int) , 1, f); 
    if(!rc) printf("could not read max_data\n");

    printf("%d\n", tmpdb->max_rows);

    tmpdb->rows = malloc(sizeof(Address) * tmpdb->max_rows);
    if(!tmpdb->rows) printf("could not allocate rows\n");

    // This dies on windows (MingW gcc), but runs fine on ubuntu!  
    rc = fread(tmpdb->rows, sizeof(Address) * tmpdb->max_rows , 1, f); 
    if(!rc) printf("could not read db\n");

    fclose(f);
    free(tmpdb->rows);
    free(tmpdb);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 'typedef'ing a struct definition is a very bad idea.  The typedef clutters the code, can be misleading, is totally unneeded, and clutters the compiler name space.  Strongly suggest removing the 'typedef' modifier and always reference the structs by 'struct <tagname>'

Comment: when the malloc for 'db' fails, there is no need to free it

Comment: when #define'ing a numeric value, the value needs to be wrapped in parens '(' and ')' to avoid text replacement errors

Comment: regarding this code block: 'if(!f) printf("Could not open file");'  when the file fails to open, NEVER continue in the code using that file pointer.  The (almost always) best practice is to report the problem, cleanup, then exit the program;  This same report problem, cleanup, exit program should also be used when malloc fails

Comment: the struct Address contains two character pointers, those char pointers, do not point to any allocated memory.  And when reading an instance of struct Address, those pointers, (typically 4 bytes each) contain no valid data.

Comment: if fread() fails, why would you expect the next call to fread() to 'properly' read the next data in the file?

Comment: @user3629249. Thanks for your feedback. Regarding the two char pointers in the Address struct, does it make sense to create such a struct on the stack, as I do in the code, or is it always preferrable to create a pointer to the struct and do all the memory allocations as needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must open your files in binary mode, with e.g. `"wb+"` and `"rb"`. This is because (especially on Windows), binary and text files are not the same.

Also, a line like

```
fwrite(&db->max_rows, sizeof(int), 1, f);
```

is better written as

```
fwrite(&db->max_rows, sizeof db->max_rows, 1, f);
```

This avoids hardcoding the type name of `max_rows`, so if that were to change the code wouldn't break. One less place to remember to change, and one fewer dependency.

And you're overwriting the `rc` return value, so you won't really catch the errors properly.

Finally, beware that doing binary I/O like this means the file won't be portable, since it will depend on the [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and exact type size choices of the compiler where it was written.

Comment: Thanks. I found the relevant documentation in http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html.

Comment: Regarding your last point, I suppose the recommended approach would be to use a serialization format like XML or another text representation?

Comment: @dxrsm That's one way, but of course it doesn't have to be text. Serializing as binary is fine, but you have to be more explicit about it. If you *want* an `int` to be 32-bit little endian on the wire, make sure that's what you're getting (typically by doing a controlled write of the proper number of bytes in the proper order).